# ¿Como hago un insert en una tabla no mappeada (sin @Entity) en Spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Tengo una tabla en la base de datos Oracle a la cual no tiene declarada llaves primarias. Por lo tanto solo requiero hacer INSERT desde Spring Boot. ¿Como puedo realizar un insert si no tengo declarada la clase @Entity?

Mi aplicación de spring boot la tengo montada en un servidor de aplicaciones con conexiones jndi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que tengo entendido deberías poder coger el objeto `JdbcTemplate` y ejecutar queries con el sin problema.

Pero no tengo demasiada experiencia con spring boot en general [mírate este artículo](https://www.java4s.com/spring-boot-tutorials/spring-boot-configure-datasource-using-jndi-with-example/) a ver si te ayuda